# Make fonts smaller in App menu or make them multi-line

Tags: gnome, fonts, gnome-dash

Hope this question was never asked before. When I press 9 dots menu icon on Gnome app drawer it opens up the big icon app menu which is ugly and okay. But the problem is app titles are big as well. For example I have LibreOffice. All I can see is bunch of "LibreOffice ...". I have to determine between Writer, Calc etc based on icon rather than title. Same with other system apps - see the screenshot below -
[image]

Comment: Gnome 40 is around the corner. Hope they'd fix this.

Answer (score 1):

As a test I opened one of the `.desktop` files for editing:

```
gedit admin:///usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop
```

Then I edited the line

```
Name=LibreOffice Writer
```

to

```
Name=LO Writer
```

That made a difference at next login.

Maybe that should be proposed for everyone?

Comment: That is one good method but not suitable for every user. +1. I'd better like it multi-line. Do you think they fixed it in Gnome 40?

Comment: @MANI: I don't know. But since there is said to be quite a few changes, I would guess that they haven't had the resources to focus on details like the one you mention in this question.